# Change the text color on select options

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have a select dropdown and I would like to change the color of the text within the dropdown when I click the actual select menu. I am using the mui.css framework for this with AngularJS 1.2

```
.mui-select > select:focus {
   outline: 0;
   height: 33px;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
   border-color: #2196F3;
   border-width: 2px;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

// HTML

```
 <div class="mui-select" id="selected-team">
      <select ng-model="rule.selectedAction" ng-options="team.name for team in teams track by team.id" required>
          <option value="">Select Team</option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure if this can be done using just CSS or would I need some jQuery like plugin to do this?

Comment: can please share the html code?

Comment: can you show us working demo ? you can use [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) for that purpose

Comment: try to define style for option instead of select: `.mui-select > select:focus option {...`